# Access site via local dev IP address => certain image path (xxx.dev) isn't replaced with IP address

Tags: ip-address

I'm accessing my site through a local IP address (192.168.1.128:3000 that mirrors xxx.dev)

In my general.php I have these settings which work fine when accessed through IP =>

[image]

I then request for 2 image transforms (one non-retina, the other retina):

[image]

But when I check the rendered source code in the browser, I notice that only my retina (big format) doesn't have the IP address in it's path, how is this possible?

[image]

This isn't that big of an issue on my desktop because it will always find the xxx.dev, but when I try to test the site on my iPhone - through the IP address - it doesn't render the retina image because it can't find the xxx.dev

Any ideas on this one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you setup the 192.168.0.129 => qualityliving.dev mapping in your hosts file?

Comment: My desktop computer has IP 192.168.0.128, my Vagrant box has IP 192.168.56.119  This is the entry in my hosts file => [link](https://cl.ly/lOLo)  
I have the BrowserSync Grunt task running which proxies the qualityliving.dev to 192.168.0.128:3000  
I don't think the problem lies there, because all other resources (images, js, css, ...) also have the IP address as their src or href [link](https://cl.ly/lOLo)  (I'm sorry for the lack of line-breaks in this comment, I must be doing something wrong here)

Comment: js resources also have the IP as their src => [link](https://cl.ly/lOjR)

Comment: Hrm... maybe a Vagrant user can chime in. A bit out of my wheel-house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue suddenly fixed itself without any changes that I'm aware of... Thanks anyway!